# JavaScript JQuery - implicit comparison between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, comparison

I have an Ajax request that returns lat/lon coordinates that are of type number.

For each response, I need to check if each of the returned values is within an array, if not add it. Heres what I have so far:

```
$.each(jqXHR.responseJSON, function (index, value) {

    if($.inArray([value.loc.coordinates[1],value.loc.coordinates[0]], settings.locations) === -1){
        console.log('adding...');
        settings.locations.push([value.loc.coordinates[1], value.loc.coordinates[0]]);
    } else {
        console.log('already have...');
    }

});
```

Testing shows that the comparison always fails, and the value is added even when it is already within seettings.locations. Can anyone advise where there issue lies?

---

**UPDATE:** OK so thanks to the comments so far I can see that this is incorrect use of inArray. Heres what I have now:

```
$.each(jqXHR.responseJSON, function (index, value) {

    $.each( settings.locations, function( key, cValue ) {

        if(value.loc.coordinates[1]+','+value.loc.coordinates[0] !== cValue){
            console.log('Adding new coords..')
            settings.locations.push([value.loc.coordinates[1], value.loc.coordinates[0]]);
        } else {
            console.log('Already have: ' +cValue );
        }

    });

});
```

Again these never evaluate to match and hence it drops in to an unlimited loop.

Comment: You can't use `$.inArray()` to look for two coordinates at once.  It simply doesn't work that way.  It looks only for a single item that must match the entire array element in order to be found.  You will need to write your own loop to search through the array.

Answer (score 0):

Please take care of how you are using $.inArray. It checks only one value at a time.

```
$.inArray(1, [1, 2]);
// output: 0 -> exists at index 0

$.inArray(2, [1, 2]);
// output: 1 -> exists at index 1

$.inArray([1, 2], [1, 2]);
// output: -1
```

Actually the first argument could not be an array.
Alternatively You can do like below:

```
$.each(jqXHR.responseJSON, function (index, value) {

    if ($.inArray(value.loc.coordinates[1], settings.locations) !== -1) {
        if ($.inArray(value.loc.coordinates[0], settings.locations) !== -1) {
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
    settings.locations.push([value.loc.coordinates[1], value.loc.coordinates[0]]);
});
```

Comment: The OP's data is slightly different, it should be `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],...]` which is passed as the second argument, the first of course is `[1,2]` or something else. He wants some kind of implicit comparison between 2 arrays.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the OP's data (see my above comment). His `settings.locations` is actually an **array of array**. Each location is an array.

Comment: I know, but $.inArray is not the appropriate method in order to compare to arrays. Because It didn't accepts an array as it's first argument. [Jquery Official Website](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)

Comment: That's why the data to store the `location` should be changed, such as by using an object instead of an array. Or simply using for-loop to check the existence.

Answer (score 0):

My solution. I decided to change the format of the stored data to be an object:

```
"37.502917,-122.501335" : true,
"37.494473,-122.499619" : true,
```

Then I can easily check for the existence:

```
 $.each(jqXHR.responseJSON, function (index, value) {
    var newLocation = value.loc.coordinates[1] + ',' + value.loc.coordinates[0];
    if (currentData[newLocation] === undefined) {
        currentData[newLocation] = currentData[newLocation] || true;
        ............
```